# Print array of images

Tags: javascript, printing

I've got an javascript array which contains image pathes.

```
var images = ["pictures/pic1.jpg", "pictures/pic2.jpg", "pictures/pic3.jpg"];
```

(The array is generated via Ajax/Json and coming from a php-script).

Now i want to print out each of the pictures.
Each picture should be printed at a separate page width `width=100%`

What is the fastest way? 
Do I have to display each image inside a `div` (which has a css page-break after style) and then print or is it possible to print the images directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but try

```
@media print {
   * 
    {    
     display: none !important;
    }

   .printable
    {
     display: block !important;
     width=100%;
     break-after: always;
     page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

and have

```
var cnt = 0;
function printImages() {
  var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
  for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.className="printable";
    img.onload=function() {
      cnt++;
      if (cnt==images.length) {
        window.print();
      }
    }
    img.src=images[i];
    container.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```